Force columns for owned entity to be lower case in Entity Framework Core 8
I'm looking for a way to force database column names to be lower case on a owned entities. My scenario is I have an Address class and a Customer class.
I have a property on the Customer class that looks like this:
public Address Address { get; set; }

The Address class has the [Owned] annotation on it and properties such as this:
public string Street { get; set; }

EF Core then assumes column names like Address_Street, but I want it to use address_street. I want this to happen across the board so I don't have to apply olumn changes for every single instance of this.
I've seen a lot of posts about conventions, but what I've seen seems to rely on classes/methods that are no longer valid, so am assuming things are different in EF Core 8.

This one from official documentation?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv That would update it in one instance. I'm looking for a solution that changes the convention across the board so I don't need to do it for each individually. A solution that applies lowercase to every single column in the database would likely cover it without even have to consider owned entities. I've updated my question to make sure it's clear I'm looking for a change in convention.

So, it is no technical problem to apply this behaviour to all needed owned entities, with some reflection magic. If you are looking for such solution, it is possible.
